# React Navigation Invariant violation: Attempt to get native tag

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am getting an error when trying to set up a simple navigation app using react-navigation.

Here's index.js:

```
/** @format */

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SecondScreen from './app/screens/SecondScreen';
import FirstScreen from './app/screens/FirstScreen';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

const App = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SecondScreen,
    FirstScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FirstScreen',
  },
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Here's FirstScreen.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class ReadingScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  render() {
    return <Button title="CLICK ME" onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectScreen')} />;
  }
}
```

When I make the initial screen the SecondScreen everything is fine, but when it's like this I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Attempt to get native tag from node not marked as "native"
```

Help would be appreciated! I've been looking for a solution all day!

Here are my versions:

```
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-navigation": "^2.12.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same error, i can't navigate, it just hangs out and throws same error but when i am debugging remotely it works, i think it has to do with cocoa pods being installed in xcode project or something.  Weird thing is that a few days ago this project did run OK.

The only different thing i did is to reinstall and update dependences in react, maybe it's an error on current react-navigation version i was version 2.11.2 and when now it is 2.12.

Yes!! Solved it, it was the version. I downgrated react-navigation from 2.12.0 to 2.11.2 and it worked!

Comment: I am started to get same error , it was working fine just few minutes ago. All I did was add react-native-phone-call, tho removing it doesn't work either. How did you downgrade?

Comment: To downgrade remove node modules folder, then go into package.json look for dependencies and change `react-navigation:2.11.2` then in terminal do `npm install` or faster installation do `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

I think its to do with your button component. You need to pass a function:

so instead of:

`onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectScreen')}`

you do:

`onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectScreen')}`

Full code:

```
export default class ReadingScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return <Button title="CLICK ME" onPress={() => navigate('SelectScreen')} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, no more red error! But, It's still not navigating, I am getting:
'Possible unhandled promise rejection (id 0):
Invariant Violation: Attempt to get native tag from node not marked as "native"
'

Comment: The same error? I tried your code and it worked for me. The only difference is my `"react": "^16.4.2"`

Comment: No it's not the same, its a yellow error and it just freezes when I click the button

Comment: does navigating to SecondScreen fix it `navigate('SecondScreen')`? Remember this is a stack navigator, it stacks a screen above the other screen. You are not trying to do something else?

Comment: Nope :(, that's what I tried. I'm just trying to change screens

Comment: Maybe its to do with native.

Comment: I have started to face the same issue. It happened after i yarn added phone call lib.

Comment: This is bizzare

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. The weird thing is, it's working as it should when I'm debugging JS remotely.

Also I noticed it only happens when I try to navigate to another screen in the stack navigator I'm already in (basically, when I try to push a screen to the stack).